# „Ein bisschen Kleber und das wird schon“

Tags: translation, modal-particle

I am told that this translates as, “A little glue and it’ll be fine.” I know „schon“ can function both as an adverb meaning “already” and as a modal particle meaning “indeed” in the context of contradicting a prior assertion, but neither of these meanings helps me here. How do we get from „das wird schon“ to “it’ll be fine”? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Schon" - like "doch" and similar words - acts as a *Modalpartikel* (mood particle?) here. The whole phrase is set and an *Ellipse* (ellipsis). although, as @guidot points out, DWDS has different opinion about that. In detail:

> das wird schon

This is a set phrase and is used in an affirmative or soothing manner. The construction is IMHO an *Ellipse* with the verb left out. (Something like "das wird schon *besser werden*", "das wird schon *funktionieren*" or similar is implied.) On the contrary [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/werden) says "werden" also has the (colloquial) meaning of "to emerge", "to be on its way to improve".

"Schon" can have many meanings but here it acts as a *Modalpartikel*. It is comparable with the english "indeed":

> This will work.
> This will indeed work.

Here "indeed" just emphasizes the fact that *it will work*, even though it might not look like it. "Schon" also implies that looks might not suggest success but despite that it will (indeed) do eventually.

One can use this phrase in an affirmative or a soothing way, addressing others or even one self:

> Q: Denkst Du, das funktioniert?
> A: Das wird schon!

*You think that works? Eventually, it will!*

Or:

> A: Mein Hund ist krank.
> B: Das wird schon.

*My dog is ill. It'll be fine.*

> A: Ich weiß nicht, was ich tun soll.
> B: Das wird schon.

*I don't know what to do. It'll work out (eventually, you will know what to do).*

For the sentence in the title there are several other adequate translations:

> A little glue and that is that.
> A little glue will go a long way.
> A little glue and you are all set.

Comment: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/werden) meaning 3 states the *on its way to improve* meaning, correctly marking it as **colloquial**.

Comment: Interesting. "werden" would basically mean "emerge" in this case. I always thought the phrase was elliptical, with some fitting verb implied.

Comment: The future tense also exists: "Das wird schon werden." "Schon" according to DWDS Bed. II,1): "drückt die Zuversicht, Überzeugung, Versicherung aus, dass ein Vorgang, Zustand eintreten wird; dient oft als beruhigender, beschwichtigender Zuspruch"

Comment: @bakunin This is a wonderfully clear and detailed answer. Thank you so much!